# How to implement a logical operation for all ArrayList elements?

Tags: java, hashmap

Im trying to solve some task and i need to ensure that all element of my List is equals to the first element and at the same time the last element satisfies some another logical operation.

I tried to solve that by using trivial "for" with Iterator, but it dont solving task of comparison all of element together at same time with some another operator.

```
for (int i=0; i<listOfValues.size()-1; i++){
                if (listOfValues.get(i).equals(listOfValues.get(i + 1))&&((listOfValues.get(listOfValues.size()-1)==listOfValues.get(i)-1)|(listOfValues.get(listOfValues.size()-1)==1))){
                    
                }
            }
...
```

Comment: You'll need a for and then a separate if outside the for.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Did I understand correctly, you suggesting to compare all elements in for body with boolean result and use that in next if?

Comment: Why would you need to use that in the next if?  It seems like you're trying to do multiple things at the same time that aren't related.

Comment: Would using a stream operation for checking that all element of your list are equal to the first element be OK for you?

Comment: @OleV.V., can i exclude last element of the list from the stream or i need to make new list with only elements i need?

Comment: Ah, the last element needs not be equal to the first? You can, for example by limiting the stream to the first (n - 1) elements where n is the size of the list; but it may not give the clearest code, I’m unsure.

Comment: [Did you have something like this in mind?](https://rextester.com/NCVEMU38291)